# Sticky header with jquery

Tags: jquery, header, sticky

I would like to create multiple two sticky headers just like in that website:
http://www.trendyol.com/Kappa/ButikDetay/8690
When you scroll down, the first header combines with the second sticky element. After that, both of them move down together. How can I do it?
Thank for advance support!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way this is accomplished is pretty easy.  You check the scroll position and if it is below a certain number you display a fixed position element at the top (and hide when the scroll position goes backup).

That being said there is a great plugin that can help:  https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints

With demo exactly what you want:  http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/

AS an update from one of the comments, http://stickyjs.com might be a more supported library.

Comment: I've had a lot of problems with that plugin, I prefer this one: http://stickyjs.com/

Answer (score 4):

use `position:sticky` to make sticky.

Here is the [article explained](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Stick-your-landings-position-sticky-lands-in-WebKit).

Comment: That's pretty nifty although not a fully supported specification (yet).